# KDE desktop environment alongside GNOME

Tags: kde, desktop-environments

I'm using Ubuntu and I would like to experience KDE desktop environment. I have installed KDE in full mode using `apt-get install` with no error but no further effects occurred. I don't know how to use my installation, start in KDE mode and switch between unity and KDE.

Comment: Log out select the session, log in.

Comment: @UriHerrera I have no other choices just the usual greeting screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Installing KDE**

To install KDE (which it sounds like you may have already done), you install one of the following packages:

- `kde-plasma-desktop`

  This will only install a minimal core of KDE apps and utilities.  Good if you want to use KDE but don't need all the applications and utilities that come with it.
- `kde-full`

  This will install a more full range of KDE applications and utilities.

  If you have other desktop environments installed this will cause you to double-up on a fair few apps (ie, have both the Gnome and KDE equivalent installed).  This is not necessarily a bad thing as it gives choice and lets you (if you want) use anything a native KDE user would use.
- `kubuntu-desktop`

  This installs the full Kubuntu desktop which includes the full KDE suite, plus all of Ubuntu's "Kubuntu" look and feel, including the splash screens and greeters.  It also installs additional applications that Kubuntu normally installs, like Kontact and Konversation.

  This is not usually recommended if you also have other desktop environments installed, because it changes the splash screen and greeter to Kubuntu.

**Selecting KDE when logging in**

- Before you enter your password upon log-in, you need to open up the drop-down that says "Ubuntu" (which will make you use Gnome/Compiz/Unity, Ubuntu's default) and change it to KDE.

Comment: There is no ubuntu choice.

Comment: I installed kde-plasma-dektop and now it works well, But I'm still confused with the behavior after the previous installation. I wonder if I can find the previous installed files somewhere and add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Hi when you are at the login screen there you can choose wich desktop you want to use like in the screenshot here [image]